# MLE of the parameters of a PDF written as an infinite sum of terms

Tags: r, mle

My question relates to the use of R for the derivation of maximum likelihood estimates of parameters when a probability distributions is expressed in the form of an infinite sum, such as the one below due to Rao, Girija et al. [image]

I wanted to see if I could reproduce the maximum likelihood estimates obtained by these authors (who used Matlab, rather than R) when the model is applied to a given set of data. My attempt is given below, although this throws up several warnings that "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length". **I know why I am getting this warning, but I do not know how to remedy it.** **How can I edit my code to overcome this?**

Also, is there a better way to handle infinite sums? Here I'm just using an arbitrary large number for n (1000).

```
library(bbmle)
svec <- list(c=1,lambda=1)
x <- scan(textConnection("0.1396263 0.1570796 0.2268928 0.2268928 0.2443461 0.3141593 0.3839724 0.4712389 0.5235988 0.5934119 0.6632251 0.6632251 0.6981317 0.7679449 0.7853982 0.8203047 0.8377580 0.8377580 0.8377580 0.8377580 0.8726646 0.9250245 0.9773844 0.9948377 1.0122910 1.0122910 1.0646508 1.0995574 1.1170107 1.1170107 1.1170107 1.1344640 1.1344640 1.1868239 1.2217305 1.2740904 1.3613568 1.3613568 1.3613568 1.4486233 1.4486233 1.5358897 1.5358897 1.5358897 1.5707963 1.6057029 1.6057029 1.6231562 1.6580628 1.6755161 1.7104227 1.7453293 1.7976891 1.8500490 1.9722221 2.0594885 2.4085544 2.6703538 2.6703538 2.7052603 3.5604717 3.7524579 3.8920842 3.9444441 4.1364303 4.1538836 4.2411501 4.2586034 4.3633231 4.3807764 4.4854962 4.6774824 4.9741884 5.5676003 5.9864793 6.1086524"))
dL <- function(x, c,lambda,n = 1000,log=TRUE) {
    k <- 0:n
    r <- log(sum(lambda*c*(x+2*k*pi)^(-c-1)*(exp(-(x+2*k*pi)^(-c))^(lambda))))
    if (log) return(r) else return(exp(r))
}
dat <- data.frame(x)
m1 <- mle2( x ~ dL(c,lambda),
            data=dat,
            start=svec,
            control=list(parscale=unlist(svec)),
            method="L-BFGS-B",
            lower=c(0,0)
      )
```

Comment: The problem is that you try to add two vectors with different length: `x` (length 76) and `2*k*pi` (length 1001 - with default settings).

Comment: What is `c` supposed to be?  It's always better to use named parameters in coding. You pass a `c` object to the x parameter of d() and you pass a `lambda` value to the c parameter.

Comment: Also. the message you are getting is not an error message but rather a warning. I also think you don't really have a handle on what a density function is supposed to do. Look at other density functions in R and note how they return a vector of the same length as their x inputs. They are also normalized so the integrals over their range of definition are unity.

Comment: How do I resolve the problem? I know why I am getting this warning, but not how to edit the code to resolve it.

Comment: @IRTFM I understand fully what a pdf is. The pdf is an infinite sum in this case. It is a genuine pdf, but how am I supposed to write this properly in the code? Suggestions on other threads on here just write a large value for n (hence n=1000 here). Also, c is a parameter.

Comment: Without knowing what is being attempted, it's difficult to offer advice. This "genuine" PDF is coming from what source?

Comment: @IRTFM I have edited the original post. I await your solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest starting out with that algorithm and making a density function that can be tested for proper behavior by integrating over its range of definition, (c(0, 2*pi). You are calling it a "probability function" but that is a term that I associate with CDF's rather than density distributions (PDF's):

```
dL <- function(x, c=1,lambda=1,n = 1000, log=FALSE) {
    k <- 0:n
    r <- sum(lambda*c*(x+2*k*pi)^(-c-1)*(exp(-(x+2*k*pi)^(-c))^(lambda)))
    if (log) {log(r) }
}
vdL <- Vectorize(dL)
integrate(vdL, 0,2*pi)
#0.999841 with absolute error < 9.3e-06
LL <- function(x, c, lambda){ -sum( log( vdL(x, c, lambda))) }
```

(I think you were trying to pack too much into your log-likelihood function so I decide to break apart the steps.)

When I ran that version I got a warning message from the final `mle2` step that I didn't like and I thought it might be the case that this density function was occasionally returning negative values, so this was my final version:

```
 dL <- function(x, c=1,lambda=1,n = 1000) {
     k <- 0:n
     r <- max( sum(lambda*c*(x+2*k*pi)^(-c-1)*(exp(-(x+2*k*pi)^(-c))^(lambda))), 0.00000001)
     
 }
 vdL <- Vectorize(dL)
 integrate(vdL, 0,2*pi)
#0.999841 with absolute error < 9.3e-06
 LL <- function(x, c, lambda){ -sum( log( vdL(x, c, lambda))) }
 (m0 <- mle2(LL,start=list(c=0.2,lambda=1),data=list(x=x)))
#------------------------
Call:
mle2(minuslogl = LL, start = list(c = 0.2, lambda = 1), data = list(x = x))

Coefficients:
        c    lambda 
0.9009665 1.1372237 

Log-likelihood: -116.96
```

(The warning and the warning-free LL numbers were the same.)

So I guess I think you were attempting to pack too much into your definition of a log-likelihood function and got tripped up somewhere. There should have been two summations, one for the density approximation and a second one for the summation of the log-likelihood. The numbers in those summations would have been different, hence the error you were seeing. Unpacking the steps allowed success at least to the extent of not throwing errors. I'm not sure what that density represents and cannot verify correctness.

As far as the question of whether there is a better way to approximate an infinite series, the answer hinges on what is known about the rate of convergence of the partial sums, and whether you can set up  a tolerance value to compare successive values and stop calculations after a smaller number of terms.

When I look at the density, it makes me wonder if it applies to some scattering process:

```
curve(vdL(x, c=.9, lambda=1.137), 0.00001, 2*pi)
```

[image]

You can examine the speed of convergence by looking at the ratios of successive terms. Here's a function that does that for the first 10 terms at an arbitrary x:

```
> ratios <- function(x, c=1, lambda=1) {lambda*c*(x+2*(1:11)*pi)^(-c-1)*(exp(-(x+2*(1:10)*pi)^(-c))^(lambda))/lambda*c*(x+2*(0:10)*pi)^(-c-1)*(exp(-(x+2*(0:10)*pi)^(-c))^(lambda)) }
> ratios(0.5)
 [1] 1.015263e-02 1.017560e-04 1.376150e-05 3.712618e-06 1.392658e-06 6.351874e-07 3.299032e-07 1.880054e-07
 [9] 1.148694e-07 7.409595e-08 4.369854e-08
Warning message:
In lambda * c * (x + 2 * (1:11) * pi)^(-c - 1) * (exp(-(x + 2 *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> ratios(0.05)
 [1] 1.755301e-08 1.235632e-04 1.541082e-05 4.024074e-06 1.482741e-06 6.686497e-07 3.445688e-07 1.952358e-07
 [9] 1.187626e-07 7.634088e-08 4.443193e-08
Warning message:
In lambda * c * (x + 2 * (1:11) * pi)^(-c - 1) * (exp(-(x + 2 *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> ratios(0.5)
 [1] 1.015263e-02 1.017560e-04 1.376150e-05 3.712618e-06 1.392658e-06 6.351874e-07 3.299032e-07 1.880054e-07
 [9] 1.148694e-07 7.409595e-08 4.369854e-08
Warning message:
In lambda * c * (x + 2 * (1:11) * pi)^(-c - 1) * (exp(-(x + 2 *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

That looks like pretty rapid convergence to me, so I'm guessing that you could use only the first 20 terms and get similar results. With 20 terms the results look like:

```
> integrate(vdL, 0,2*pi)
0.9924498 with absolute error < 9.3e-06
> (m0 <- mle2(LL,start=list(c=0.2,lambda=1),data=list(x=x)))

Call:
mle2(minuslogl = LL, start = list(c = 0.2, lambda = 1), data = list(x = x))

Coefficients:
        c    lambda 
0.9542066 1.1098169 

Log-likelihood: -117.83
```

Since you never attempt to interpret a LL in isolation but rather look at differences, I'm guessing that the minor difference will not affect your inferences adversely.

Comment: Thank you. That is much more helpful. This is the first time I have come across a PDF as a series, so the MLE stumped me. As for the PDF/CDF discrepancy, different authors use different terminology. I've seen 'distribution function' applied to both PDF and CDF. Formally, I tend to reference PDF and CDF as their full titles.

Comment: More intriguing is that in the referenced paper, the value for the max log likelihood obtained in Matlab rather than R is −119.5338. What do you suppose is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: Maybe they only included the first 8 terms? The -LL seems to be decreasing with smaller numbers of terms. I get to -119.53 when n=5.

Comment: My hypothesis is strongly supported by the fact that the estimates of c and Lambda for that data (1.013006, 1.077321 ) under the "Wrapped exponentiated inverted Weibull distribution" (pg 173) with my code using n=5 also now agree to 4 decimal places with the results in the table on page 177 of what appears to be the "cited" work the text "Angular Statistics" by those two authors. Not sure what the "et.al" might refer to since there are only two authors listed. They apparently used an automated solver rather than using their own code.